# NGINX Variable for SSL Protocols

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to configure nginx to present different SSL protocols based off the soruce IP for example if the IP is an internal 10.0.0.0/8 IP it will present from TLSv1 to TLSv3 but if the source IP is a public one it will only provide TLSv1.2 minimum.

```
`I was was hoping I could achieve this like below

geo $private_ip {
    default 0;
    10.0.0.0/8 1;
    172.16.0.0/12 1;
    192.168.0.0/16 1;
}

then using map as below

map $private_ip $ssl_protocols {
     default "TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3";
     1 "TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3";
}

then in the sever block I am trying to set this variable

ssl_protocols $ssl_protocols;`
```

However I get this error *nginx: [emerg] invalid value "$ssl_protocols"* which makes me think I can pass this as a variable and it doesn't accept this

the server listens on a specific port and I cant really define a server name or listen IP as I don't want to add extra layers.

Is this possible?

I was expecting I could pass the ssl protocols as a variable depending on the client source IP.

I have done a redirect in the server block is private_ip = 1  to a different port and then present the weaker protocols here. This does work but then the new port is just exposed externally even if I return a 444 or 403 if the IP is public, plus this doesn't really suit my needs.